A REST API from inside a container is NOT accessible from other container on the same host
I have a REST API running from a container but the port is published so I can access the web service from any machine using https://myapi.com/myservice. Everything is good.
Now, I have another application running on a different container on the same host, which should consumes the web service (running in the other container). For some reason, the web service always returns 400 Bad Request when trying to consume from the app in the container...
If trying the app from the same host or outside, it always works! I'm not sure if I 'm missing some configuration, but calling the API from inside a container, shouldn't be the same if using the https://myapi.com/myservice URL?
I would appreciate any help.
Gus

400 Bad Request which means that it is hitting a server and it is responding to your request. Could you just be sending an invalid request?

Please share a [mcve]

For first step,maybe you should check DNS resolution name inside of the container that you're tying to call.
or trying to do the telnet first whether the expected port can be called inside container. Just for crosscheck.
Or better use container port directly to call the other container
For example, if the API container is named api-service, you can access it using http://api-service:port/myservice
instead of using public domain

I think he has already established that he is getting 400 response code. That mean connection is fine. Its a client error code, so he is sending bad data as input.

Have you checked the payload request, is it sending the expected request as per API specificiation ? do you have nginx config inside your container ? can check whether the config able to receive such a file request or other related settings.
